# Python REST API access custom header values

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-views, django-rest-framework

i am using django rest-framework for posting or getting a data from the client application. The client application is sending a custom header along with the request. How can i access that custom header value in rest api.

Custome-Header-Key: ASDQWERYHH #This is the custom header set from the client.

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [request.META](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META) dictionary.

> With the exception of CONTENT_LENGTH and CONTENT_TYPE, as given above, any HTTP headers in the request are converted to META keys by converting all characters to uppercase, replacing any hyphens with underscores and adding an HTTP_ prefix to the name. So, for example, a header called X-Bender would be mapped to the META key HTTP_X_BENDER.

So to get the header value in your example you could do:

```
request.META['HTTP_CUSTOM_HEADER_KEY']
```